# Tensorflow csv reader error: "Quote inside a string has to be escaped by another quote"

Tags: python, csv, tensorflow

I have a csv file, which I'm pretty sure doesn't have " in, which I'm trying to reading using the following code:

```
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(["../data/train_no_empty_rows.txt"])
# train_no_empty_rows

reader = tf.TextLineReader()
key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)


record_defaults = [tf.constant(['p'], dtype=tf.string),    # Column 0
               tf.constant(['p'], dtype=tf.string),    # Column 1
               tf.constant(['p'], dtype=tf.string)]   # Column 2 


col1, col2, col3 = tf.decode_csv(
value, record_defaults=record_defaults,field_delim=" ")

features = tf.pack([col2, col3])
with tf.Session() as sess:
  # Start populating the filename queue.
  coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
  threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
  for i in range(1200):
    # Retrieve a single instance:
    example, label = sess.run([features, col1])

  coord.request_stop()
  coord.join(threads)
```

But when I run it I get this error:

```
InvalidArgumentError: Quote inside a string has to be escaped by another quote
 [[Node: DecodeCSV_25 = DecodeCSV[OUT_TYPE=[DT_STRING, DT_STRING, DT_STRING], 
field_delim=" ", 
_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]
(ReaderRead_25:1, Const_75, Const_76, Const_77)]]
```

Which I think I could debug, but I can't find where it references which entry in the csv file it's having problems with. It's quite a large csv file, and the first 100 or so entries don't have this problem. As I said, I can't find any ", and ' seems to parse fine in tests. Is there some way I can find the troublesome entry?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to find the troublesome entry would be to add a [`tf.Print()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/0.6.0/api_docs/python/control_flow_ops.html#Print) operator before the [`tf.decode_csv()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/0.6.0/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#decode_csv):

```
# ...

# Prints out the contents of `key` and `value` every time the op executes.
value = tf.Print(value, [key, value])

col1, col2, col3 = tf.decode_csv(
    value, record_defaults=record_defaults, field_delim=" ")

# ...
```

The last logged entry before the failure should indicate which input was invalid. Hopefully the root cause becomes apparent when you make this modification.